# How do I change the infinite spinning of a font-awesome icon?

Tags: attributes, font-awesome

How do I change the infinite spinning of a font-awesome to, say 360 degree spin?
`.fa-spin-hover:hover {
  -webkit-animation: fa-spin 1s infinite linear;
  animation: fa-spin 1s infinite linear;
}`

When I try to replace "infinite" with "360deg" the code doesn't work. Is there a way around it?

Comment: What do you mean by 360 degree spin? Do you want it to spin a single time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.fa-spin-hover:hover{
     -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
     transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
```

Refer this link
http://www.gadgetronicx.com/spinning-social-icons-hover-css-html/